# AWS Elastic BeanStalk updates environment indefinitely updates my environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just tried adding new environment variables in the software section of the modify menu. I'm not sure if this would be causing the problem but it's the last change I made. When I try to view the logs it begins to update endlessly again, every now and then it stops and displays the health of the instance then continues again. I restarted the application and the problem is persisting. I'm using the t2 micro instance, is it just too small? I've been able to insert 6 million rows into my database no problem.

This happens

> The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-0bd297052e3448bfa].

Then

> Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1].

Then

> Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0bd297052e3448bfa'. Aborting the operation.

Then I restarted

> Environment health has transitioned from Info to Ok. Application restart completed 52 seconds ago and took 14 minutes.

Then I tried viewing the logs and of course it started to update again

> requestEnvironmentInfo is starting.

Is AWS usually this insufferable??

Thanks

Comment: With environment/Image you use? Docker, Java, Pyhton ... ?

Comment: I'm using NodeJS!